# How do I get all the instance variable names and values recursively using reflection in java

Tags: java, object, reflection, recursion

Basically I need to print all the instance variable names and their values in a name value pair format recursively. Say my class structure is as below

```
public class SomeClass{

private String classDescription;
private Animals animals;
private Birds birds;
private List<Insects> insects;
private Map<String, Reptiles> others;

}

public class Animals{

private Dogs dogs;
private Cats cats;
private List<Mammals> mammalsList;

}

public class Dogs{
private String variable1;
private long variable2;
}
```

For the above class structure where I have chain of object references, I need to print 
the instance variable name and the corresponding values recursively. Code would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at reflexion. Type it in your favourite search engine and you should find more than enough informations ;)

Comment: Tired of searching, all the link that I got was having working code and example for one object but not chain of objects in recursive way

Comment: I you know how to do that for one object, you should also be able to do it for many?!

Comment: In case of `List<Insects>`, do you need the variables in `List` or `Insect` ?

Comment: variables in insect, repeating as many times as in the list

Comment: @Sammy: Basically I am not aware of how to handle this for user defined datatypes. If the Class has only basic datatypes, then using the Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); I can easily do that. If you are aware, I appreciate that you can help me :)

Answer (score 5):

I guess this code might help. I haven't added the functionality for processing `Map`, but it works with `List`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{
    SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
    Class c = s.getClass();
    getMembers(c);
}

public static void getMembers(Class c) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{
    Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field f : fields) 
    {
        if (f.getType().isPrimitive() || f.getType().equals(String.class))
        {
            System.out.println(c.getSimpleName() + ": " + f.getName() + " is a "+ f.getType().getSimpleName());
        }
        else 
        {
            if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) 
            {
                String s = f.toGenericString();
                String type = s.split("\\<")[1].split("\\>")[0];
                Class clazz = Class.forName(type);
                System.out.println(c.getSimpleName()+ ": "+ f.getName()+ " is a collection of "+ clazz.getSimpleName());
                getMembers(clazz);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(c.getSimpleName() + ": " + f.getName() + " is a "+ f.getType().getSimpleName());
                getMembers(f.getType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One more simple example to get name value with reflection:

```
public void getNameValue() {
    try {
        RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(this);
        Field field = RingtoneManager.class.getField("ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER");
        String type = field.getType().getSimpleName();
        String name = field.getName();
        String value = (String)field.get(ringtoneManager);
        Log.e(TAG,type + " " + name + " = " + value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```